# HTML page through gmail

Tags: html, smtp, gmail, newsletter

I need to send a newsletter and have some questions. I have written my newsletter in basic html (using tables and no CSS) and saved it locally.

I used to use Eudora (eek!) to send my newsletter because it allowed raw HTML in email templates & signature files. Now I use Gmail for all of my emails.

**Question 1:** Can I get that html code into a new email using Gmail?

**Question 2:** To send the newsletter successfully I need to send the newsletter **from** a specific address **to** a specific address on our server. Will this form of security still work through gmail? My sending email's SMTP server settings are correctly setup.

**Question 3:** How do I know what my email will look like in common email readers?

Comment: I don't recommend newsletters being sent out locally from your own computer.  Depending on your ISP, it's too easy to violate their anti-spam policy and get suspended even without a complaint (too many Bcc's, etc.).  If you have a website hosting account, you could send out from there with dedicated newsletter software, but again, too many rules and too easy to get shut down.  There are free third party services like [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/) that take all the responsibility of sending in bulk while conforming to any anti-spam rules.  They also provide nice HTML newsletter templates.

Comment: I use hMail on my server for the emails and newsletter, so it's not sent through my ISP. It's all configured already for newsletters.

Answer (score 0):

1,I don't know about your email marketing software. But this [email marketing software](http://www.phpnewsletter.org) could help you to import or export your email HTML code.

3, you could preview your emails for testing for the SPAM. That means you can send your edited emails to some common email ISP to test them whether they are SPAM or inbox.